# Why a number logs as NaN?

Tags: javascript

Working on google map. I have markers on the map taken from a station object (with position & number of bikes in). the marker onclick event show the number of bikes. I would like to show this number - 1 but it return "NaN".

I tried to use ParseInt() & Number() and to find answers on the web.
Sorry I'm a beginner the answer could be simple but I'm blocked on this problem.

```
// My station object


//station tab which will contains all the data
const stationsTab = [];

//Give attributes to station object from data
getInfos().then(function(data){
    data.forEach(function(info){
            const station =
              {
                  stationLocation : info.position,
                  availableBikesNumber : info.available_bikes
              };

        // Put stations in a tab
            stationsTab.push(station);

        // a marker for each station
            mark = new google.maps.Marker
            ({
                map : map,
                position : station.stationLocation,
                bikes : station.availableBikesNumber,
                icon : 'images/bluemarker.png';
});

// It gives me the first number. It runs
document.getElementById("free_bikes").innerHTML = station.availableBikesNumber + "bikes"; // For example station.availableBikesNumber is 9, returns "9 bikes"

// Event when should log number - 1. It doesn't run

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    document.getElementById("free_bikes").innerHTML = station.availableBikesNumber - 1 + " bikes"; //returns "NaN bikes"
    var temp = Number(station.availableBikesNumber) - 1;
    console.log(typeof station.availableBikesNumber); //returns "undefined
    console.log(Number(temp)); //returns "NaN"
    console.log(typeof temp); //returns "number"
    document.getElementById("free_bikes").innerHTML = temp + " bikes"; //returns "NaN bikes"
  }, false);
```

Comment: `station.availableBikesNumber` is undefined. `Number(undefined)` is `NaN`. `NaN - 1` is `NaN`. `Number(NaN)` is `NaN`. The issue is that `station.availableBikesNumber` should **not** be undefined, shouldn't it? Perhaps you wanted `e.availableBikesNumber`?

Comment: Yes. But it cames from JSON API I didn't create it and if I put "parseInt(station.availableBikesNumber)" in the object it makes the same returns.

Comment: `station` does not exist in the submit button callback.

Comment: I'm not sure to get it. I have to change `(e)` in `(station)` and get `station(availableBikesNumber)`  or to create another function re-using `temp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think here `station` may null , because of that  `var temp = Number(station.availableBikesNumber) - 1;` returns NaN. and

> `NUMBER(temp)`

is NaN because `temp` not contains any number

please check your `station` variable.

Comment: _var temp = Number(station.availableBikesNumber) - 1; returns undefined._ No. This returns `NaN`, because Number(undefined) is `NaN`.

Comment: with `submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {...})` `station` is not defined at HTMLButtonElement. But with `submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(station) {...})` it's an object but not the one of const `station`

Comment: this `station` looks to be the click position on the map and there is no other var called station